# Cannot complete the New controller action through Pundit gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pundit

I have a Ruby on Rails web app where users creates notes.  The note belongs to the user that created it.

I installed the [Pundit gem](https://github.com/elabs/pundit#installation) to create authorizations, specifically an admin role.

I would like for a user to be able to:

- create, update, or delete *their* notes

And for an admin to be able to do the same for **any user's** notes.

When I log in as an admin, I can create a new note.  When I log in as a member, I cannot create a new note.  I get instantly redirected to the root page, and never even brought to the new note page.

Here is the flash error message I receive:

```
not allowed to new? this #<Note:0x007fe2ca17bc18>
```

Before installing Pundit, members **were** able to create a new note.  So I assume it has something to do with my policies.

Here are the relevant methods from my `application_policy.rb` file:

```
  def index?
    false
  end

  def show?
    scope.where(:id => record.id).exists?
  end

  def create?
    user.present?
  end

  def new?
    create?
  end

  def update?
    user.present? && (record.user == user || user.admin?)
  end

  def edit?
    update?
  end

  def destroy?
    update?
  end
```

Here is my `note_policy.rb` file:

```
class NotePolicy < ApplicationPolicy

  def create?
    user.present? && (record.user == user || user.admin?)
  end

  def new?
    create?
  end

  def update?
    create?
  end

  def destroy?
    update?
  end

end
```

And here are the relevant actions from my `notes_controller.rb` file:

```
  def new
    @note = Note.new
    authorize @note
  end

  def create
    @note = Note.new(notes_params)
    @note.user = current_user
    authorize @note
    if @note.save
      redirect_to notes_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

I am trying to figure out why an admin can create a new note, but a member cannot.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `new` action, the authorization check is being made using `NotePolicy#create?`. See chain of calls below:

`NotePolicy#new?` --> `ApplicationPolicy#new?` --> `NotePolicy#create?`

A new Note (`@note = Note.new`) won't pass the authorization check made in `NotePolicy#create?`.

Add a `new?` method to `NotePolicy` that implements the authorization logic you want.

**ADDED**

This `create?` method will not pass for a new note (`Note.new`).

```
def create?
  user.present? && (record.user == user || user.admin?)
end
```

To confirm why that's the case you can debug by adding a line like `puts "#{user.present?} #{record.user} #{user}"` at the beginning of the `create?` method.

You'll see the values of these variables in the server output or `logs/development.log`.

Comment: I thought that since `note_policy` inherits from `application_policy`, and since I already have the correct `new method` in `application_policy`, that I would be covered?  I thought that was part of inheritance, and DRY?

In any case, I added: `def new create?  end`  to `note_policy`, and it still is not working.  Receiving the same error message. Thanks.

Comment: **ANSWER** came from @EliotSykes.  To `note_policy` add `def new  user.present?  end`  Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

Is it missing a `new?` method in your NotePolicy?

Comment: I think that'd fix it.

Comment: I tried adding `new?`, still not working.  Same error message.  I will add it to the posting above for full reference.  Thanks.